# why is "\n" removed when I write replaceAll("\\p{P}", ""), because "\\p{P}" is a regular expression for PUNCTATION only

Tags: java, regex

why is "\n" removed when I write `replaceAll("\\p{P}", "")`, because "\p{P}" is a regular expression for PUNCTATION only. "\n" line break is not a punctuation mark?

For example, after this regular expression, a group of lines

```
1,2,3
4.5
6.7?8
```

converted to `12345678`

why was the line break removed?

Comment: Present your code as [example], so we can figure out what removes the new-line `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

The regex [POSIX character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix) for *puncutation* (`\p{P}` or `\p{Punct}`) does not remove line-breaks.

See the [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/znRPL0):

```java
String multiline = "1,2,3\n4.5\n6.7?8";
System.out.println(multiline.replaceAll("\\p{P}", ""));
```

Prints the string with line-breaks preserved:

```
123
45
678
```

Comment: Why then lines glued after this regular expression? it was so 1,2,3 \n
4.5 \n
6.7?8                                                                                                                                   but it became so 12345678

Comment: @DimaMsuVmk22 Please update your question with the code first.

Comment: i can not update((( i dont know why I can't edit

Comment: i read from file by method readLine() (BufferedReader)

Comment: @DimaMsuVmk22 Once you could update and [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72637244/string-pool-in-java-calculation-of-expressions-with-the-literats-at-the-compilat) .. Please take the [tour] and read the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)